# Core data Parent Child Context Implementation Confusion

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Am using a parent-child context syncing data with cloud kit. Am facing a problem of child overwriting the parent data. I know this is how it works but is there anything that can be done.

Below is the exact scenario.

Model

1. Parent Entity : A
2. Child Entity : B

A->>B is one to many relationship.

Context:

1. Parent Context (MOC) :- Used for CRUD operation by users.
2. Child MOC (CMOC) :- Used for syncing data from cloud kit.

Senario:

1. A parent is deleted from child context
2. A child for that parent is inserted on parent context.

If the save of child occurs, it overwrite the parent moc while leaving the newly inserted child without a parent.

So this leaves a child which don't have any reference parent.

Answer (score 0):

When parent is deleted from child context, it will also be deleted from the parent context when save is performed.  Changes from child contexts are propagated to parent context. This is by design.

What are you trying to accomplish? There may be another way.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes @oyalhi, that by design. I want the no child records stays in the DB without a parent. While deleting Parent i do check(NSfetch) that their are no child records. But if a child is saved after this step, then the child context do not have any idea about this newly inserted child in the parent context and so when the child context get saved, it deletes the parent leaving the newly inserted child relationship to parent as NULL. So i want to know if there is any way though which this can be avoided.